# Run django+nginx+celery+gunicorn+daphne on docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-for-windows

I have been trying for long to run my django application using docker but unable to do so. Application works fine using normal architecture like deploying on ubunutu compute engine.

Below is the Dockerfile.prod

```
#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN adduser app
RUN usermod -a -G app app


# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install python3-pip nano  -y
RUN apt-get install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev python-dev -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

RUN ls

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

Below is docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile:  Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn Reporting.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - redis

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db


  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
    ports:
      - 1338:80
    depends_on:
      - web

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.12-alpine


  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq


  daphne:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile:  Dockerfile.prod
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 Reporting.asgi:application
    expose:
      - 8001
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db   
      - redis
      - rabbitmq 


  celery:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile:  Dockerfile.prod
    command: celery -A Reporting worker -l info -n worker1@%h --concurrency=3
    volumes:
      - app_volume:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
    depends_on:
      - redis


  celery2:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile:  Dockerfile.prod
    command: celery -A Reporting worker -l info -Q status  -n worker2@%h --concurrency=1
    volumes:
      - app_volume:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - rabbitmq


  celery-beat:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile:  Dockerfile.prod
    command: celery -A Reporting beat --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler -l info
    volumes:
      - app_volume:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - rabbitmq

volumes:
  app_volume:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

I am getting the below errors

daphne

```
daphne_1       | /home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh: 7: nc: not found
```

web

```
web_1          | /home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh: 7: nc: not found
```

celerybeat

```
celery-beat_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery-beat_1  |   File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
celery-beat_1  |     "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
celery-beat_1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

celery

```
celery_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1       |   File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
celery_1       |     "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
celery_1       | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

celery2

```
celery2_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery2_1      |   File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
celery2_1      |     "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
celery2_1      | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Here is the directory structure

[image]

entrypoint.prod.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear

exec "$@"
```

**Can you please guide me what am i doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you please share the requirements.txt? Or can you confirm if `django` is present in the requirements.txt file? 
Also, you need to add `netcat` (nc) to the list of tools you are installing as `RUN apt-get install python3-pip nano netcat -y`

Comment: @kmmanoj Hi I have shared requirements.txt . Django is there. Can you please guide me why do i need to add ```netcat``` ? I run with the same dependencies on vm and it works fine?

Comment: Regarding `netcat` full fledged ubuntu OS have netcat preinstalled in them. Ubuntu docker images don't have netcat installed in them by default.

Comment: @kmmanoj i do not understand why ```entrypoint.prod.sh```  is not found both for daphne and web services.When i first started learning docker, I ran a small starter project with same configurations except i was using python-3.8-alpine image and that django project worked fine.

Comment: I don't have a clear picture of what may be going wrong. May be you want to try building the docker image locally: `docker build -t app .` and then troubleshooting it doing a `run` and `exec`. You may want to check the environment variables `env` and uploaded directory structure.

Comment: What is in the entrypoint script?  The Celery containers mount a named volume over a directory `/usr/src/app`, hiding everything that was in the image on that path and replacing it with something else; is this supposed to be the same `/home/app` directory that's in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added entrypoint.prod.sh . I did two things after reading your comment. First i replaced volume for celery, celery2 and celery-beat with same volume as web i.e ```static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles```. and then rerun the  docker-compse ```docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build``` I got the same errors.

Comment: @DavidMaze Second thing i did is i removed volume from celery, celery2 and celery-beat  and then again rerun ```docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build``` still i got the same errors. I am very new to docker. Please pardon me if i am doing something stupid.

Comment: I followed these two tutorials to learn deploying django project on docker. https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/  and https://testdriven.io/blog/django-celery-periodic-tasks/